# How can i change the text format of a Excel Cell using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I am currently writing an application (C#) to generate reports in a excel file, based on other reports.

The problem is that, once get an number from a certain sheet, and copy to another one, the destination cell is not formated correctly, and the number does no display correctly.

```
E.g : 
Number from source : 14.34 
Number on destination : 14.345661
```

How do i format the destination cell to force the number formating to be the same as the source cell.

Thanks !

Comment: Various examples here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-2d450d95-2630-43b8-bf06-ccee7cbe6864?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of a given cell/range in excel can be set via code.

```
public void SetCustomFormat(string format, int r, int c)
{
    ((Excel.Range)xlWks.Cells[r, c]).NumberFormat = format;
}
```

In your specific case, I believe you would need to use the format "#.00" or "#.##"

Comment: Cant seen to find this xlWks variable. Is this the Worksheet ?

Comment: Yes, that's the worksheet variable.  I have it defined internally to my own code using the xlWks variable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet from some code I've got in use, to show you the general pattern for formatting cells.  Obviously, there are some variables declared, but it should show you what you need.

```
sheet.get_Range("A" + CurrentRowIndex.ToString(), ColPrefix + CurrentRowIndex.ToString()).Font.Bold = true;
sheet.get_Range("A" + CurrentRowIndex.ToString(), ColPrefix + CurrentRowIndex.ToString()).Interior.Color = Color.Silver.ToArgb();
sheet.get_Range("A" + CurrentRowIndex.ToString(), ColPrefix + CurrentRowIndex.ToString()).BorderAround(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, null);
sheet.get_Range("A" + CompetencyStartRowIndex.ToString(), ColPrefix + CurrentRowIndex.ToString()).BorderAround(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, null);
```

That first line, assuming CurrentRowIndex = 1 and ColPrefix = "B", replacing the variables with the resulting values would translate into

```
sheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;
```

At any rate, you want to set the numberformat.  (Coming..)

```
sheet.Cells[Row, Column].NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is not what i am looking for.
I am looking for a way to format text inside the cell, not the cell itself like the background or the font format.

I want the text to be interpreted in another way

Comment: The last line in my answer seems to answer what you're looking for.  Perhaps I should delete the rest, as it's extraneous. Sometimes I foolishly try to be complete when I should be concise.  ;-)