# C# to Excel set custom date display and value

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, date, datetime-format

Given a certain date, I want to set the **value** of a cell with a DateTime object, but without the "Time" information. For example, for today the value would just be **"29/06/2012"** and not **"29/06/2012 16:54:36"**.

Concerning the display, for today's date I want it to be written like this (it is in french, I don't know how it would be in english): **"29 juin"** and not **"29/06/2012"**.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT** : I just took a look at the display formatting I need in Excel, it is "jj mmmm" ("dd mmmm" in C#). But the cell, though taking the value, does not take the formatting. Here is a piece of code:

```
                 cell.Value = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
                 cell.NumberFormat = "jj mmmm";
```

I also tried:

```
                 cell.Value = DateTime.Now;
                 cell.NumberFormat = "jj mmmm";
```

In that case, the display formatting is OK, but the cell value contains the Time information, which is not OK.

Comment: So, you want to set a cell to a certain day, and set the display format to "dd MMM" or "dd MMMM" with a culture of "fr-FR"?

Comment: @Jodrell To be simple, I want the value to be "dd/MM/YYYY" and the display to be "dd MMMM" in french culture (or even english, it could help)

Comment: @GianT971 - just change "DateTime.Now" to "DateTime.Date" and the time will be zero'd out.

Comment: @ChrisGessler post this as an answer

Comment: @GianT971 - Do me (us) a favor.  Next time show your code in your question when you ask it.  I was under the impression that you wanted to get rid of the "00:00:00" time portion that comes with ALL DateTime objects and can only be removed with formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change `DateTime.Now` to `DateTime.Date` and the time will be zero'd out

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720498/how-can-i-change-the-text-format-of-a-excel-cell-using-c/10720603#10720603) StackOverflow question, and my answer to it.  It will allow you to set the custom format for the cell directly in the excel sheet, from there you just need to research what the different date format strings are.

That is only helpful if you are using excel automation though.

Otherwise, formatting the DateTime.ToString output will be better.  Once again, researching the different DateStringFormatting options will be helpful to you.

Final option.  Directly change the template, not using automation.  Goto the cell and manually change the cell format until the display is what you want.  This does not change the actual data, just its display.

**UPDATE**

There are two specific issues to deal with.

Issue one is making sure excel recognizes that this IS a date.  To that end, make certain that the date data itself is formatted en-US.  Why, because Microsoft is dumb, and doesn't recognize international date formats.

Issue two is the display format for the cell.  For a 3 letter abbreviation of the month, use the string `d mmm`.  If you want the full month name, use `d-mmmm`.

I was testing and noted that excel refused to treat 29/06/2012 16:54:36 as a date, but it accepted 06/29/2012 16:54:36 without an issue.  As I said, microsoft is dumb.

Comment: I have been modifying the NumberFormat property of the cell since the beginning, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know why

Comment: Excel is silly, and wont recognize international date formats easily.  Windows, if your region is setup correctly, might.

Comment: Indeed, when Excel recognizes the data as a date, the NumberFormat works and the display is OK (+1 for this). But How can I get rid of the Time information? That is the main problem actually

Comment: Well, if you want the data there, but not displayed...NumberFormat is actually the correct field to use.  I listed the formats up in the answer there.  if that's not working for you...then check issue 1, making sure excel recognizes it as a date.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has a method called ToShortDateString

Comment: I know, but this is only ok for the value of the cell. I also need a custom formatting for the display

Answer (score 0):

```
// Displays Fri 29 Aug
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("ddd d MMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")));
```

This would be a good resource for you:  [msdn custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the problem is not the dateTime formatting, but the difference between the value and the formatting of the cell in Excel

Comment: @GianT971 Gotcha, looks to me like manually changing the template of the column in your excel file then(?) Good luck to you, sorry Excel is.. what it is.